# send data between 2 functions in the same controller

Tags: .net, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem in my controller. I would like to send an object "EtapeItineraire" from one function to another.

When I call to the first function I receive the good data.

[[image]]

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PrintString(string id)
{
     List<EtapeItineraire> id2 = new List<EtapeItineraire>();

     id2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EtapeItineraire>>(id);
     return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf(
                    "ViewPrint",
                    id2) { FileName = "Cartographie.pdf" };
}
```

*Rotativa is a library that can convert View in pdf file*

But I call the second function with rotativa, the data didn't pass.

[[image]]

```
 public ActionResult ViewPrint(List<EtapeItineraire> id)
 {
      return View(id);
 }
```

Model :

```
public class EtapeItineraire
{
     public string distance { get; set; }
     public string instruction { get; set; }

     public EtapeItineraire(string distance, string instruction)
     {
         this.distance = distance;
         this.instruction = instruction;
     }
     public EtapeItineraire() { }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should look like this

```
return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("ViewPrint", new { id = id2}) { FileName = "Cartographie.pdf" };
```

according to examples of [Rotativa
  on GitHub](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa)

Usage:

```
public ActionResult PrintIndex()
{
    return new ActionAsPdf("Index", new { name = "Giorgio" }) { FileName = "Test.pdf" };
}

public ActionResult Index(string name)
{
    ViewBag.Message = string.Format("Hello {0} to ASP.NET MVC!", name);

    return View();
}
```